How rare are nebulae which emit H-Beta/H-Gamma/H-Delta? (Balmer series)
Most of the visible light emission nebulae have a lot H-alpha emissions, and because of that appear red.
But why are other Balmer emissions much rarer? Do they need a hotter environment which is rarely found in nebulae?

I don’t know the mechanisms behind that, but I do know that the Horsehead Nebula  (or, technically, IC 434, which is behind it) is better seen with an hydrogen-beta filter.

The other Balmer emission lines aren't rarer, but they are weaker, due to the quantum-mechanical nature of the different transitions within the hydrogen atom; the temperature of the nebula has almost no effect. (H-alpha is typically about 2.9 times brighter than H-beta, for example.)
